# How is the difference between 2 normal distributions a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, standard-deviation

I've learned that if we sum or subtract 2 normal distributions, the result would be another normal distribution with $\mu=\mu_{1}\pm\mu_{2}$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^2+\sigma_{2}^2}$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hf0ne3rcxy

Here is a graph of a normal distribution with $\mu=\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^2+\sigma_{2}^2}$ along with a graph of the difference between two normal distributions, $N(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1})$ and $N(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2})$.

Clearly, they're not the same, the result of the subtraction doesn't even look like a normal distribution.

Why can we assume that the result is a normal distribution?

Comment: Its the difference between two normal random variables that is again normal, not the difference between two distribution functions...

Comment: @MichaelM I'm a little confused. Normal random variables have normal distribution functions. If the difference between them results in a normal random variable, doesn't that mean that the resulting random variable will have a normal distribution function?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It seems that I do not understand your question.

Comment: @MichaelM If the difference between 2 normal random variables A and B results in a new normal random variable C, what would be the normal distribution function of C?

Comment: Your quoted variance result need independence!

Comment: You don't *assume* it is a normal, you *prove*  it. There are multiple ways, but all must have been asked&answered here before! Some ways: characteristic functions, moment generating functions, convolution integral, and maybe others ... sum or diference does not matter, its the same technique

Comment: Your example subtracts one density function from the other.  Unless the density functions are equal, that *never* results in a density function, because somewhere it must be less than zero.